# How to improve code for scraping reddit using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, praw

My objective is to find out on what other subreddit users from r/(subreddit) are posting on; you can see my code below. It works pretty well, but I am curious to know if I could improve it by:

First, restricting my code so that it only considers users only once (i.e. not collect the posting history twice for the same user) and, secondly, by adding a minimum of 5 posts per user before extracting his/her info (i.e. if the user wrote less than 5 posts in his reddit life, my code would not consider him).

Many thanks!

```
import pandas as data

import datetime as time

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id = '#####',

client_secret = '#####',

username = '#####',

password = '#####',

user_agent = '#####')

columns = { "User":[], "Subreddit":[], "Title":[], "Description":[], "Timestamp":[]}

for submission in reddit.subreddit("ENTER A SUBREDDIT").new(limit=100):

user = reddit.redditor('{}'.format(submission.author))

for sub in user.submissions.new(limit=100):

columns["User"].append(sub.author)

columns["Subreddit"].append(sub.subreddit)

columns["Title"].append(sub.title)

columns["Description"].append(sub.selftext)

columns["Timestamp"].append(sub.created)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. Code review is off-topic here, but you can try our sister site [codereview.se]. (Please make sure to take _their_ tour, read _their_ on-topic page, and read _their_ How To Ask page to make sure you ask an on-topic question.)

Comment: If you can narrow this down to _one concrete question_, it might still be on-topic here. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

To do both of the things that you wanted you would do something like this:

```
import pandas as data
import datetime as time

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id = '#####',    
client_secret = '#####',    
username = '#####',    
password = '#####',    
user_agent = '#####')

columns = { "User":[], "Subreddit":[], "Title":[], "Description":[], "Timestamp":[]}

for submission in reddit.subreddit("ENTER A SUBREDDIT").new(limit=100):
    if submission.author in columns['User']: # skip over authors already seen
        continue
    user = reddit.redditor('{}'.format(submission.author))
    user_posts = list(user.submissions.new(limit=100))

    if len(user_posts) <= 5: # skip over users that have less than 5 posts
        continue
    for sub in user_posts:
        columns["User"].append(sub.author)
        columns["Subreddit"].append(sub.subreddit)
        columns["Title"].append(sub.title)
        columns["Description"].append(sub.selftext)
        columns["Timestamp"].append(sub.created)
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew for taking the time to answer. Much appreciated!